# Как удалить приложение с play market

Tags: android, google-play

Добрый день!

Занимаюсь тестирование приложения. Есть бета версия в Play Market.
Случайно опубликовал рабочую версию. Я не хочу, чтобы приложение было опубликовано так как оно еще кривое, сырое и вообще не надо, чтобы оно было опубликовано.

Но Play Market не дает просто удалить рабочую версию приложения из публикации. Я могу его деактивировать в расширенной версии консоли, но он не даст сохранить ничего, пока я не загружу в замен другой АПК. Так же можно удалить приложение из публикации полностью, но тогда удаляется и бета версия продукта.

Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Answer (score 12):

По состоянию на 10.12.2017 вижу доступным вариант только деактивировать.
Не нужна даже загрузка нового АПК.

Хоть и полностью удалить выпуск не дают, но в поисковике и в самом маркете его не будет.
Найти эту кнопку можно по такому пути в плей консоли:

Ваше приложение -> Вид в магазине -> Цены и распространение -> Доступность приложений -> отменить публикацию.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

*GooglePlay* уже более года как заблокировал удаление "активных приложений", то есть таких которые установлены на устройстве.

Удалить приложение с *GooglePlay* можно попробовать после того как оно будет удалено со всех устройств. До того момента, можно только деактивировать, и тем самым прекратить доступ для скачивания новыми пользователями. Учитывая то, что много мобильных телефонов просто сдаются на разборку или выбрасываются (без удаления приложений естественно) - то такие "мертвые" устройства будут гарантией того, что приложение вы не удалите никогда с *GooglePlay*.

Разве что поменяется политика Гугла, и если устройство неактивно в течении какого то периода, то такое устройство не будет учитываться в списке устройств с установленным приложением.

Информацию почерпнул из [этого источника](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-ru/1fR3jNWcXUg.)

Comment: Могли бы Вы добавить ссылку на это решение Google?

Comment: Сделал выводы из: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-ru/1fR3jNWcXUg. Наткнулся когда интересовался созданием аккаунта разработчика и возможностью его удаления если вдруг понадобится. Понял что видимо потом его можно будет удалить только если продать все приложения другим разработчикам. Ну или другие неособо приятные варианты типа вести себя плохо и быть наказанным.

Comment: Не переходит по ссылке в статье. Только по той что в комментариях.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте В Google Play -> Консоль Разработчика->Ваше приложение->Удалить из Google play(Рядом с открыть в Google Play)

Comment: так можно, но тогда версия бета теста пропадает.

Answer (score 1):

Перейти на https://play.google.com/apps/publish
Раздел «приложение».
Далее, «файлы apk».
Переключится в расширенный режим.
Деактивировать.