# Play market. Как скрыть рабочую версию и опубликовать тестовую

Tags: google-play

Я опубликовал рабочую версию в маркет. Можно ли ее деактивировать и настроить альфа тестирование? Или хотя бы как правильно после загрузки робочей версии настроить альфа-тестирование? Нашел [пост](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/439782/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81-play-market), но ответа так никто и не дал...